# Codenamone project runs on simulator but not on device

Tags: codenameone

I have built an app with codenameone. Tested on the simulator, everything appears fine. However when I build an app, it does not work well on the device. I use the sqlite database and the app is supposed to download data from the server and put into the local sqlite database. From the behaviour, apparently this is not happening. I have struggled to find a way to debug the app with vey little success.
What is the best wy to proceed?

Comment: I have the debug running on Android Studio now. Problem was not installing build tools version 27.

Comment: How did you install the downloaded sqlite database?

Comment: just downloaded using rest and inserted into the database.

Comment: Where did you do that in the code? Did you do this after the applications start method completed and returned the main thread? This is important. You should release the main thread, use callSerially to defer action until after start completed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the debug running now on Android Studio. I needed to install build tools version 27 and  upgrade the gradle. I should be able to fix this.